# Window Socket programming in NSIS

Tags: sockets, nsis

I am trying to create a socket in the .nsi file to check whether the socket will get created successfully or not to check for port availability. So any help with respect to **windows socket** programmin in **nsis** is highly appreciated.

thank u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

!ifndef AF_INET
!define AF_INET 2
!define SOCK_STREAM 1
!define IPPROTO_TCP 6
!define INADDR_ANY 0
!define SOL_SOCKET 0xffff
!define /math SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE 0xffffffff ^ 0x4
!endif

Function QueryCanBindToIP4TCPPort
Exch $0
Push $1
Push $2
Push $0 ;Push port
System::Alloc 16 ;WSADATA & sockaddr_in
System::Call 'Ws2_32::WSAStartup(i 2,isr2)i.r0'
${If} $0 = 0
    System::Call 'Ws2_32::socket(i ${AF_INET},i ${SOCK_STREAM},i ${IPPROTO_TCP})i.r1 ?e'
    Pop $0
    ${If} $1 <> -1
        System::Call 'Ws2_32::setsockopt(ir1,i ${SOL_SOCKET},i ${SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE},*i 1,i4)i.r0'
        System::Call 'Ws2_32::htons(iss)i.s' ;Convert port (and leaves the original push on the stack)
        ;Skipping htonl on address since INADDR_ANY is 0
        System::Call '*$2(&i2 ${AF_INET},&i2 s,&i4 ${INADDR_ANY},&i8 0)'
        System::Call 'Ws2_32::bind(ir1,ir2,i16)i.r0'
        ${If} $0 = 0
            System::Call 'Ws2_32::listen(ir1,i0)i.r0'
            ;Listening here but once we hit WSACleanup the port will be free again (This is fine if all you need to do is make sure no app is bound to the port at this moment)
            ; System::Call 'Ws2_32::closesocket(ir1)'
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    System::Call 'Ws2_32::WSACleanup()' ;Remove this call to leave the port open for the duration of the installer
${EndIf}
System::Free $2
Pop $2 ;Throw away port
Pop $2
Pop $1
Exch $0
FunctionEnd

Section
Push 666
call QueryCanBindToIP4TCPPort
Pop $0
${If} $0 = 0
    DetailPrint "Bind OK"
${Else}
    DetailPrint "Bind Failed!"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: If i try to use the same port more than once to call this function QueryCanBindToIP4TCPPort, then installation is getting aborted :(

Comment: Why would you check the same port more than once? Try un-commenting the closesocket call

Comment: `${If} $0 = 0 `is this ok for checking the value of $0  OR we have to use this `${If} $0 == 0 `

Comment: @sr164w = is correct, == is string test and the wrong thing to use here. If you are checking a lot of ports you can move the WSAStartup and cleanup calls out of the function if you want to...

Comment: Check $0 after the pop and compare with list of windows error messages. You might want to write a custom plugin instead of fighting the system plugin...

Comment: since INADDR_ANY 0 skipping htonl in the code, but if i need to give my machine ip or some n/w adapter ip to which i m connected  (not localhost ip), what shud i do??

Comment: System::Call 'Ws2_32::htonl(ir9)i.r9' if the IP (as a 32bit number) is in $9, then replace "&i4 ${INADDR_ANY}" with "&i4 r9"

Comment: yes, i did the same thing but i am getting bind error 10014 [i.e Bad address. The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call. This error occurs if an application passes an invalid pointer value, or if the length of the buffer is too small. For instance, if the length of an argument, which is a sockaddr structure, is smaller than the sizeof(SOCKADDR). ]

Comment: The docs on the bind page says: "The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call.

This error is returned if the name parameter is NULL, the name or namelen parameter is not a valid part of the user address space, the namelen parameter is too small, the name parameter contains an incorrect address format for the associated address family, or the first two bytes of the memory block specified by name do not match the address family associated with the socket descriptor s." so are you sure you got the IP as a 4 byte number?

Comment: Or you can use inet_addr() but it is probably best if you use some other programming language first and when you got it working you can convert to system plugin syntax!

Comment: That is a string, I told you it needs to be a 32 bit number, you need to use inet_addr() but like I said, please code this in some other language first...

Answer (score -1):

As NSIS doesn't have any network functionality either built-in or in any plugins that I could find, the simplest solution in my opinion is to make a very small program that tries to create a listening socket on the specified port (where the port can either be hard-coded or passed as an argument). This program can then be used in the install script to check if the port is available.

Comment: Is it using System.dll ? can u pls refer me to good document or link related to this

Comment: @sr164w The system plugin calls the winapi directly so you should read the system readme for syntax/usage and check MSDN for the socket docs. I'll see if I can come up with a working example, tomorrow maybe...