# check for particular port availability on particular IP(both Ipv4 and Ipv6) in nsis

Tags: port, nsis, ipv6

I am displaying all connected Ip addresses in a drop down and I need to check whether the particular port is free in particular Ip(both Ipv4 and Ipv6).Ip will be selected from dropdown, How can I check whether the selected Ip is Ipv4 or Ipv6 and then how can i check free port availability in ipv6 Ip case

Comment: What makes you sure that if it's free at install time it'll be free by the next reboot? (Or any other arbitrary point in the future)

Comment: What I would like to know is **1.** Is there any windows api (can be used in .nsi file) which tells the passed Ip is Ipv4 or Ipv6. **2.** In Ipv4 we use inet_addr to convert string addr to network address, Is there any other windows api which will do this same for Ipv6 Ip?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you keep asking basically the same question [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846885/window-socket-programming-in-nsis) and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292100/check-for-port-availabilty-using-iphlpapi-dll-in-nsis)? The answer is always the same: There are no existing NSIS plugins that can do this AFAIK so your options are:

- Write a new plugin
- Call the native windows api with the system plugin
- Use nsExec to execute a external tool like netstat

Comment: this question is to know abt how to differentiate selected ip address is ipv6 or ipv4?

Comment: I am sorry If the way of asking all my questions seems the same to u. I tried to give the whole same contect in all my question. I will correct this going forward

Comment: If all you want to do is check if an address is IPv6, you have many functions to choose from: WSAStringToAddress, inet_pton, getaddrinfo or RtlIpv6StringToAddress. Trying to listen on a port would require changes to the sample code I wrote for you in another answer...

Comment: Hi, <br/>  `code` System::Call 'Ws2_32::inet_pton(ir6,tr4,ir5)i.r0?e' ;r6->af_family(23),r4->ip as string,r5 must be the output structure.  <br/>
pop $7  ; inet_pton return value- this is 1 as success  <br/>
System::Call '*$2(&i4 ${AF_INET6},&i4 r3,&i8 0,&i16 r5,&i16 0)'  ; sockaddr6 structure needed for bind function  <br/>
System::Call 'Ws2_32::bind(ir1,ir2,i16)i.r0?e'  <br/> `code` Above bind function returns 10014 Bad address  <br/> could you please help what has gone wrong in the above structure defnition.

Comment: sockaddr_in6 is probably closer to something like (&i2,&i2,&i4,&i16,&i4). To use the system plugin you really need know C and have the SDK installed...